# Associations, create a task for a project from project index view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an association between a project and a task.

A project has_many taks and a task belongs_to a project.

My model is working great. I can create tasks from project and so on.

My problem comes when I want to add a button on the project index view to add task to a
project.

**What I want is something like that**

*(project index view)*

Project 1 Show, edit, destroy, add_task

Project 2 Show, edit, destroy, add_task

So that when I click add_task of project 1 I’m redirected to a new task form to create a task for that project.

I’ve added <%= link_to 'add_task', new_task_path(:project_id =>
project) %> in the project index view, so when I click on add_task, it redirects me to /task/new?project_id=1

but when I submit the task, the task is not linked to the project.

How can I get the project_id?

Does anyone has a tutorial or an example of how should I do?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Oscar suggested you might want to add an extra field in your form which submits the project_id to the params. then in either ur update or create function you can create the record using the parameter value, although on an hidden field make sure u set the value correctly.

```
<%= f.hidden_field :project_id, :value => project.id%>
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I missed the value attribution. I'll try it.

Comment: But how can I get the value from the url? /task/new?project_id=1

Comment: For retrieving URL/URI data rails comes with ActiveRecord::Request hash wich can be returned by request method. try using gem pry on request.env and see what data is in range. from refers to protocols etc. it's awesome

Answer (score 0):

In your form, add an hidden field for the project id

```
<%= f.hidden_field :project_id %>
```

Edit: Put this in your new action too:

```
@task = Task.new(:project_id => params[:project_id])
```

Comment: The problem is that the actual key value is not submitted like this u will need to set the value by chaining the :value key.